Bold numbers within section using zref-clever
Using the zref-clever package, I number theorems within section, and I want the reference number to appear in bold font.
I tried using the option reffont=\textbf, but only the section number is in bold, not the number of the theorem:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap, reffont=\textbf}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{theorem}\label{t}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\zcref{t}: the second 1 is not bold.

\end{document}



\textbf expects an argument, which you can't specify at this point, so it is grabbing the first token. Use \bfseries instead, which will be applied within the group:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap, reffont=\bfseries}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}

\section{Section 1}

\begin{theorem}\label{t}
A theorem.
\end{theorem}

\zcref{t}: the second 1 is now bold.

\end{document}



Excellent, thanks! I just add one comment in case someone stumbles on the same problem: to avoid italic numbers, one should similarly use reffont=\upshape, and not reffont=\textup as I mistakenly tried...
